# Module "punycode" has been externalized for browser compatability

Tags: hash, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am trying to use the '@ensdomains/eth-ens-namehash' package to hash an input.
I am using it in combination with 'pinia'.
I call on this method in Nuxt3.

This is the code:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia"
import namehash from "@ensdomains/eth-ens-namehash"
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'


export const exampleMethod = defineStore('example', {

    state: () => {
        return{
            hash: String

        }
    },

    actions: {
        method(input) {
            globalThis.Buffer = Buffer
            this.hash = namehash.hash(input).toString()
        }
    }

}
```

When trying to call 'method' I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module "punycode" has been externalized
> for browser compatibility. Cannot access "punycode.ucs2" in client
> code.

Comment: The answer is in the error: the package is not meant to be run on the client, only on the server.

Comment: Yes. But how do I do that?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve with your package. You can run it on places where the app is only running server-side. So, you can skip all the parts where you do have `globalThis` because it does not allow for `window` anyway.

Comment: I want to have an user input which I then hash. So I guess the user input happens definitely on the client side. Would it be possible to do the hashing on the server side?

Comment: You can send a request to your server and get a response out from it that you could then display on your frontend, for sure. Did you checked this one? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server

Comment: I haven't, thx. I'll see if I can make it work.